# Index Spool (Eager Spool), Difference in number of row before and after the operator

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016

I was optimizing one of the Stored Procedure for which I went through the execution plan of it.

In the execution plan I see the operator Index Spool (Eager Spool).

There I see it is taking 1759 rows as input.

[image]

And returning 69494 rows.

[image]

Just wanted to know how does it work and how is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the downstream query operator there?  Nested loops?  Have you read https://sqlperformance.com/2019/11/sql-performance/eager-index-spool-optimizer?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Nope it's hash match.